# Trying to make ease-in-out-expo timing function using standard css3

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, timing

The standards timing functions of CSS3 don't have ease-in-out-expo.

The standard ease-in-out is [HERE - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#ease-in-out)

[image]

But I want to make it like easeInOutExpo seen [HERE - easings.net](http://easings.net/#easeInOutExpo)

[image]

I'm real new to timing-function so was struggling mightily with it. Please help.

Edit:
I found this code in `jquery.easing.1.3.js` but I don't know how to convert it to `cubic-bezier`'s four arguments.

```
easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    if (t==0) return b;
    if (t==d) return b+c;
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
    return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
},
```

Comment: i found this helper site and this is the standard ```ease-in-out``` [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.42,0,.58,1) anyone know the numbers for ```ease-in-out-expo```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The css for easeInOutExpo [is on the page you linked to](http://easings.net/#easeInOutExpo):

```
div {
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1); }
```

See this also on [cubic bezier](http://cubic-bezier.com/#1,0,0,1)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GA6XV/)**

Comment: I was looking for timing js math functions for decades... Thank you very much!